# Con Axios y Vue Como puedo agregar proxy a la instancia

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios, nuxt

**Tengo la siguiente instancia en axios:**

```js
import axios from "axios";
import router from "../router";
import store from "../store/store";

let BaseApi = axios.create({
  baseURL: process.env.VUE_APP_URL+"/api"
});



let Api = function() {
  let token = localStorage.getItem("token");

  if (token) {
    BaseApi.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"] = `Bearer ${token}`;
    BaseApi.defaults.headers.common["Requested"] = `XMLHttpRequest`;
  }

  BaseApi.interceptors.response.use(function (response) {
    return response;
  }, function (error) {
    if (error.response.status === 401) {
      router.push({ name: "Home" });
      localStorage.removeItem("token");
      store.commit("LOGIN", false);
    }
    return Promise.reject(error);
  });

  return BaseApi;
};

export default Api;
```

Requiero utilizar proxy como lo aplica Nuxt.js para que las peticiones a la API REST me vallan mediante el proxy.

> **Ejemplo:** Cliente: http:localhost:8080 Backend: http:localhost:8000

Actualmente mi peticion HTTP: `http://localhost:8000/api/getDatos`

Como quiero que salga: `http://localhost:8000/backend/api/getDatos` (En Nuxt se puede pero no se en vue 2.9 como aplicarlo)

Answer (score 0):

Encontre la solucion en dev con lo siguiente:

En **vue.config.js**

```js
module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    /* https: true, */
    proxy: {
      "^/backend/": {
        /* context: () => true, */
        target: "http://10.10.6.220:8000", //Local 
        pathRewrite: { "^/backend/": "/api/" },
        secure: false,
        changeOrigin: true,
        logLevel: "debug" 
      }
    }
  }
};
```

y en mi instancia:  **baseURL: "/backend/"**

Esto en local funciona perfecto.

**

> Pero en produccion no funciona.

**

Comment: También puedes editar la pregunta, agregando la información parcial del desarrollo de la pregunta, o agregando información complementaria que sirva de soporte a la pregunta inicial. Sin cambiar la esencia de la pregunta inicial.